# Updating a list based on another list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists of users.

In the first the users have the following fields - fname,lname, UserDetailsId,FocusStart,FocusEnd,isActive

In the second list the users have  - fname, lname, UserDetailsId,totalTime, FocusStart, FocusEnd.

What I am aiming to do is : when the value isActive from the first list equals to 'true' and the userDetailsId equeals UserDetailsId from the second list I want the FocusStart and FocusEnd in the second list to be equals to the values of the matched element in the first list.

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Here is how I get the first list :

```
var list = listWRUD.
            Join(db.UsersDetails,
            o => o.UserDetailsId, od => od.identtyUserId,
            (o, od) => new
            {
                fname = od.FirstName,
                lname = od.LastName,
                UserDetailsId = o.UserDetailsId,
                FocusStart = o.FocusStart,
                FocusEnd = o.FocusEnd,
                isActive = o.isActive
            }).ToList();

        var a = from x in list
        group x by new { x.fname, x.lname, x.UserDetailsId } into g
        select new RolesUsersViewModel(g.Key.UserDetailsId, g.Key.fname, g.Key.lname, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(g.Sum(x => (x.FocusEnd - x.FocusStart).TotalMilliseconds)));
```

And here is the second one :

```
List<RolesUsersViewModel> list_users = a.ToList<RolesUsersViewModel>();
```

What i've got so far is :

```
var allActive = list.Where(item => item.isActive == true);

        foreach (var p in list_users.Join(allActive, item => item.userId, item => item.UserDetailsId, (x, y) => new { L2 = x, L1 = y }))
        {
            p.L2.FocusStart = p.L1.FocusStart;
            p.L2.FocusEnd = p.L1.FocusEnd;
        }
```

Sadly, this code seems to give me some random results. A date is set to the records in the second list even if there are no records with isActive==true in the first.

The ViewModel :

public class RolesUsersViewModel
{
    public RolesUsersViewModel(string userDetailsId, string FirstName, string LastName, TimeSpan totalex)
    {

```
    userId = userDetailsId;
    fname = FirstName;
    lname = LastName;
    total = totalex;
}

public RolesUsersViewModel(DateTime focusStart, DateTime focusEnd)//
{

    FocusStart = focusStart;
    FocusEnd = focusEnd;
}

public string userId { get; set; }
public string fname { get; set; }
public string lname { get; set; }
public TimeSpan total { get; set; }
public DateTime FocusStart { get; set; }//
public DateTime FocusEnd { get; set; }//
```

}

Comment: what do you mean `I want the FocusStart and FocusEnd in the second list to be equals to the values of the matched element in the first list.`? Do you want to assign the FocusStart and FocustEnd?

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes, that's correct.

Comment: Where does `item.userId` come from in the join?

Comment: the second list, @GertArnold

Comment: Yeah, I mean, it's a property of `RolesUsersViewModel`, but is it equal to `UserDetailsId`?

Comment: yes, it is equal to that.

Comment: OK, if there are `0` active items in the first list, so `allActive` is an empty list, you should already find dates set in `list_users` even before the join. This means it's not related to the join, but to something you do in `RolesUsersViewModel`.

Comment: Well, not much happening there (apart from a constructor that doesn't match). But did you see my point about the join? *That* can't be the cause of unexpected data values.

Comment: @GertArnold, maybe i wasn't clear enough in my question, but i never said that this was causing the problem. The cause is probably my bad code and lack of knowledge. :D Thanks for your input. I will figure it somehow, mayabe I will ask again.

Comment: Sure, feel free to edit your question if you know more. It will be bumped to the front page again if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (var p in list_users)
{
    // Get all the items that have matching UserDetailsId
    var targets = allActive.Where(x => x.UserDetailsId == p.UserDetailsId);

    // Now assign the properties
    // my assumption is that the above query should return
    // a single record. If my assumption is true then use 
    // Single or SingleOrDefault and then you do not need
    // the loop below but just a simple assignment 
    foreach(var thisTarget in targets)
    {
        p.FocusStart = thisTarget.FocusStart;
        p.Focused = thisTarget.FocusEnd;
    } 
}
```

Comment: on thisTarget i got "property of indexer...cannot be assigned to". It is read only."

Comment: i dont think so, it has { get; set; }, which tells me it isn't. But obviously my knowledge is limited.